# Directory Organizer: Organizing a given directory by moving files into categories according to their type

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, python-3.x, file-system

My Windows desktop is messy with many files of different types here and there, therefore I thought of writing a program to organize it, and other directories too, for me. Here is my code:

```
import os
import shutil


class File:
    """Represents a computer file.

    attributes: path, name, extension
    """
    def __init__(self, path):
        """Inintializes a File object.

        file_path: str
        """        
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            self.path = path
            self.name = os.path.basename(path)
            self.extension = os.path.splitext(self.path)[1].lower()
        else:
            raise FileNotFoundError("This is not a valid file")

    def is_document(self):
        """Returns whether file is a document."""
        extensions = ('.htm', '.docx', '.docm', '.doc', '.dotx',
                    '.dotm', '.pdf', '.xps', '.rtf',
                    '.txt', '.xml', '.odt', '.wps', '.accdb',
                    '.mdb', '.adp', '.xlsx', '.xlsm', '.xls',
                    '.xlsb', '.xltx', '.xltm', '.xlt', '.htm'
                    '.csv', '.prn', '.dif', '.ods', '.xlam',
                    '.slk', '.pptx', '.pptm', '.ppt', '.potx',
                    '.potm', '.pot', '.ppsx', '.ppsm', '.epub')
        return self.extension in extensions

    def is_photo(self):
        """Returns whether file is a photo."""
        extensions = ('.png', '.jpeg', '.jpg')
        return self.extension in extensions

    def is_media(self):
        """Returns whether file is a media file."""
        extensions = ('.mp3', '.mp4', '.flv', '.amr', '.mpg', '.avi', '.mov', '.webm', '.rm')
        return self.extension in extensions

    def is_executable(self):
        """Returns whether file is an exeutable."""
        return self.extension == '.exe'

    def is_archive(self):
        """Returns whether file is a compressed file."""
        extensions = ('.rar', '.zip')
        return self.extension in extensions

    def type(self):
        """Returns a string representing the type of file."""
        if self.is_document():
            return 'document'
        elif self.is_photo():
            return 'photo'
        elif self.is_media():
            return 'media'
        elif self.is_executable():
            return 'executable'
        elif self.is_archive():
            return 'archive'
        else:
            return 'other'

    def move(self, other):
        """Moves the file to a given directory."""
        Folder(other)

        try:
            shutil.move(self.path, other)

        except:       
            print('Was not moved successfully: ', self.path)
            print()


class Folder:
    """Represents a computer folder.

    attributes: path, name
    """
    def __init__(self, path):
        """Initializes a Folder object.

        path: str
        """

        if not os.path.isdir(path):
            raise FileNotFoundError(path + ' is not a valid directory')

        else:
            self.path = path
            self.name = os.path.basename(path)


    def is_empty(self):
        """Returns whether a folder is empty."""
        return os.listdir(self.path) == []


def dir_path(message):
    """Asks the user to enter a string specifing
    a directory.

    message: str

    Returns: str
    """    
    while True:
        dir_path = input(message)

        print('')

        if os.path.isdir(dir_path):
            return dir_path

        print('Not a valid directory. Try again.\n')


def move_files(source, target):
    """Moves files in a given directory to folders working as
    categories, based on their type."""
    Folder(source)
    Folder(target)

    categories = ('Document', 'Executable', 'Archive', 'Media', 'Photo', 'Other')
    create_folders(target, categories)

    for item in os.listdir(source):
        full_path = os.path.join(source, item)
        if os.path.isfile(full_path):
            file = File(full_path)
            category = os.path.join(target, file.type().title())

            print('Move: ', full_path)
            print()

            file.move(category)


def create_folders(directory, names):
    """Creates one or more folders in a given directory."""
    target = Folder(directory)

    try:
        for name in names:
            full_path = os.path.join(directory, name)
            os.mkdir(full_path)

    except FileExistsError:
        print(full_path, ': Exists already')


def main():            
    source = dir_path('Path of directory to organize: ')
    name = 'Directory Organizer'
    target = os.path.join(source, name)    
    create_folders(source, (name,))
    move_files(source, target)

    print('\nDone')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In addition to getting my code reviewed I have some questions regarding it:

- Should I in `create_folders` use `pass` instead of printing a message?
- I thought of writing a function that will categorize files existing in a given a directory based on their type. And will return a dictionary in which *key* is a string representing a category and *value* is a list of strings representing paths of files that belong to this category. Then another function will traverse this dictionary and move files. But I thought that this will just slow my code down. Will this be better?
- Should I care about *"access denied errors"*?
- I feel that `move_files` is not good enough. Am I right? If so how should it be refactored?

Answer (score 2):

There is quite a lot of repetition in the way you determine the file type. Plus, this approach does not scale well. What if you would have a *dictionary of file type names as keys and a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset)  of extensions as values* which you would dynamically transform into a map between an extension and a file type:

```
TYPE_EXTENSIONS = {
    'document': frozenset(['.htm', '.docx', '.docm', '.doc', '.dotx',
                           '.dotm', '.pdf', '.xps', '.rtf',
                           '.txt', '.xml', '.odt', '.wps', '.accdb',
                           '.mdb', '.adp', '.xlsx', '.xlsm', '.xls',
                           '.xlsb', '.xltx', '.xltm', '.xlt', '.htm'
                           '.csv', '.prn', '.dif', '.ods', '.xlam',
                           '.slk', '.pptx', '.pptm', '.ppt', '.potx',
                           '.potm', '.pot', '.ppsx', '.ppsm', '.epub']),
    'photo': frozenset(['.png', '.jpeg', '.jpg']),
    'media': frozenset(['.mp3', '.mp4', '.flv', '.amr', '.mpg', '.avi', '.mov', '.webm', '.rm']),
    'executable': frozenset(['.exe']),
    'archive': frozenset(['.rar', '.zip'])
}

EXTENSION_TYPES = {value: key 
                   for value in values
                   for key, values in TYPE_EXTENSIONS.items()}
```

Now, the `type()` method would simply look like:

```
def type(self):
    """Returns a string representing the type of file."""
    return EXTENSION_TYPES.get(self.extension, 'other')
```

And you would not need all the `is_*()` methods anymore.

Comment: I'd go a step further and transform `FILE_TYPES` into a dictionary with the keys and values inverted.

Comment: @200_success really good idea, I've adjusted the answer appropriately. Thanks!